Find expressions for probabilities and post-measurement states corresponding to a given POVM
I came across this exercise trying to understand POVMs and I can not figure it out:
Suppose Alice and Bob share a composite quantum system in the state $\rho^{AB}$. Alice performs a measurement on her system described by a POVM $\{\Lambda_x\}_{x \in [m]}$, and records the outcome $x$ in a classical system $X$. Show that the post-measurement state can be expressed as a cq-state of the form
$\sigma^{XB} = \sum_{x \in [m]} p_x \lvert x \rangle \langle x \rvert^{X} \otimes \sigma_x^B$.
Express the probabilities $p_x$, and density matrices $\sigma_x^B$, in terms of $\Lambda_x$ and $\rho^{AB}$.
From what I have learned, the post measurement state is given by:
$\sigma^{AB}_x={\frac{(M_x\otimes\ I^B)\rho^{AB}(M_x^*\otimes\ I^B)}{Trace((M_x\otimes\ I^B)\rho^{AB}(M_x^*\otimes\ I^B))}}$
Where $\Lambda_x=M_x^*M_x$
And so Bob's system conditioned on Alice obtaining outcome $x$ is:
$\sigma^{AB}_x={\frac{Trace_A(M_x\otimes\ I^B)\rho^{AB}(M_x^*\otimes\ I^B)}{Trace((M_x\otimes\ I^B)\rho^{AB}(M_x^*\otimes\ I^B))}}$
and the peobability to obatin an outcome $x$ is:
$p_x=Trace((M_x\otimes\ I^B)\rho^{AB}(M_x^*\otimes\ I^B))$
These are the definitions, am I correct?
And how do I go from here? I am kind of stuck.
Thank you.

Beware that $\Lambda_x=M_x^*M_x$ has multiple solutions for $M_x$ since $M_x' = UM_x$ is also a solution. Although it doesn't affect the final answer.

You need to use the facts that the trace is cyclic, i.e.,
$$\operatorname{tr}(MN) = \operatorname{tr}(NM),$$
and that the partial trace is partially cyclic, i.e.,
$$\operatorname{tr}_A[M^{AB} (N^A \otimes I^B)] = \operatorname{tr}_A[(N^A \otimes I^B)M^{AB} ].$$

Can you kindly elaborate? after applying this trace property I got the $\sigma_x^B =\frac{Trace_A(\rho^{AB}(\Lambda_x \otimes I^B))}{p_x}$ but how does this help me get the required expression?

This is already the required expression as far as I understood.

Oh. I think I might misunderstood the question. Dont we need to show that this expression: $\sigma^{AB} = \sum_{x=1}^{m} p_x \sigma_x^{AB} = \sum_{x=1}^{m} p_x \frac{\left( \left( M_x \otimes I^B \right) \rho^{AB} \left( M_x^* \otimes I^B \right) \right)}{p_x} = \sum_{x=1}^{m} \left( M_x \otimes I^B \right) \rho^{AB} \left( M_x^* \otimes I^B \right)$  is equal to this expression: $\sigma^{XB}=\sum_{x \in [m]} \left| x \right\rangle \left\langle x \right|^{X} \otimes \text{Tr}_{A} \left( \left( M_x \otimes I^B \right) \rho^{AB} \left( M_x^* \otimes I^B \right) \right)$ ?

No, the question is not asking you what the global post-measurement state is. That's impossible to know, because you are given only the POVM, not the measurement operators. By assumption the state on Alice's side is discarded and replaced with $|x\rangle \langle x|$. The only thing you can do is compute $\sigma^B_x$, which you have already done.

So what does the writer mean by "Show that the post-measurement state can be expressed as a cq-state of the form..."? How do I show this formally and rigorously? does mentioning " By assumption the state on Alice's side is discarded and replaced with..." enough? is it really just by the definition of the POVM? Thank you so much for all your help. I misunderstood the question completely.

I don't know, ask whoever wrote the question.
